# Detect if word typed by user matches a string in Array List in Java

Tags: java, string, arraylist, keyevent

I am trying to create a game like Typer Shark in Java. I am having a problem detecting whether a string typed by a user matches an element in an Array List. I tried doing it this way:

```
    char key = e.getKeyChar();
    ArrayList<String> word = new ArrayList<String>();
    word.add("hello");
    word.add("red");
    word.add("blue");
    int counter = 0;

    for(String temp:word){
        for(int i=0; i<temp.length();i++){
            if(key==temp.charAt(i))
                counter++;
            else
                break;
        }
        if(counter==temp.length())
          System.out.println("Correct");
    }
```

I am not sure whether I am in the right track. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I tried doing it using a text field, it worked but the player has to press enter before the program will find a match in the array list. I am trying to find if it is possible to match the typed word without pressing enter (just by using the keyTyped in Java). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not resetting `counter` for each word. Move it inside of the outside `for` loop. You also need to remember previous characters.

Also consider using `String.startsWith`.

Alternative to remembering previous characters, you could remember which words previously matched. `java.util.BitSet` would be ideal for this.

Re EDIT: Assuming you are using Swing (or AWT), if you add a `DocumentListener` to the `JTextField`'s `Document` then run you code on `insertUpdate` and `removeUpdate` (`changedUpdate` means something else), then you can ignore `ActionListener`.